# Django Middleware is not able to process view functions correctly

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am trying to do login/logout using Django Middleware.  I have gone through few tutorials but all are posted with old versions.  I am trying to hardcode the except function inside middleware instead of having in setting.py as follow:

middleware.py:

```
EXEMPT_FUNC = ['Accounts:login', 'Accounts:logout', 'Accounts:register']

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_FUNC)

        if path == reverse('Accounts:logout').lstrip('/'):
            logout(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated() and url_is_exempt:
            return redirect('User:home')
        elif request.user.is_authenticated() or url_is_exempt:
            return None
        else:
            return redirect('Accounts:login')
```

url.py:

```
app_name = 'Accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('register', views.register_view, name='register')
]
```

Above code is not working as intended, please help on what am I doing wrong.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working as intended?". What is going wrong? Note that the path, and the name of the *view* are two different things. The views do not contain `'Accounts:login'`, hence it will indeed not match. Furthermore `is_authenticated` is turned into a property since Django-1.11 I think.

Comment: Its not forcing user to login first.  I don't have any sessions or cookies defined so I am expecting when i start server it goes to login page.  I think I have issue with my logic, where its trying to match the view fuction it does not match correctly.  I hope this further clarifies.

Comment: Finally its working.

Answer (score 1):

Finally its working. 
Here is what I changed.

middleware.py:

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout

from Accounts import views

EXEMPT_PATH = ['login', 'logout', 'register']

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        exempt = False

        if path in EXEMPT_PATH:
            exempt = True

        if path == 'logout':
            logout(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated and exempt:
            return redirect('User:home')
        elif request.user.is_authenticated or exempt:
            return None
        else: 
            return redirect('Accounts:login')
```

With this approach I don't need to modify settings.py.

I hope this helps.